# Keeping only the roots containing a specified key with specified value from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array and I try to remove the root of it if it does not contain a certain key with a certain value

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [parent] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [settings] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3
                                            [thekey] => 1
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 5
                                            [thekey] => 2
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                      [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [settings] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 4
                                            [thekey] => 2
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [parent_id] => 0
            [settings] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [thekey] => 2
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [thekey] => 2
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

If I remove all [thekey] that do not contain the value 1, I expect the next result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [parent] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [settings] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3
                                            [thekey] => 1
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I tried a function but I got stuck in the recursion...

```
function removekey($array, $key,$eq)
{
    foreach($array as $k => $v)
    {
        if(is_array($v) && $k != $key )
        {
            foreach($array[$k]['settings'] as $si => $sa)
            {
                if($sa[$key]<>$eq)
                {
                    if(count($array[$k]['settings'])>=1)
                    {unset($array[$k]['settings'][$si]);}
                    else{unset($array[$k]);}
                }
            }
        }
        elseif($k == $key)
        {
            unset($array[$k]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
$result=removekey($array, 'thekey',1);
```

Comment: Does your array have dynamical depth?

Comment: @El_Vanja It has no fixed depth.

Comment: But the only dynamic part is `parent` and `settings`? Meaning one or the other could occur?

Comment: @El_Vanja settings have only one level and can occur in any parent or directly in first level of root. Parent can go to any depth.

Comment: Yeah, I meant if there is a `parent` present at a level, then `settings` cannot be present at the same level?